# How to restrict php exec() only execute R script?

Tags: php

I use PHP `exec()` to execute an R script like this:

`exec("Rscript foo.R", $return);`

But I've heard that it's very dangerous to use `exec` on the server.
How can I restrict `exec` to execute only R scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it's kind of dangerous. I wouldn't use exec for that, to be honest. But if you really want to use it, just check if  R file exists before forwarding it's name to exec. Of course, you should also ensure that the file has only R extension and the name doesn't contain relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec

exec is used to run process in background...

We use this

for eg: my report take at least 20-30 min, as it have many join and trillion of record. So, what we did is we use exec to run our script in background and pop message "We will send you an email with in 30min, no need to wait you can do other stuff... etc.,

Comment: Then what should be done to run the process in background